# Unable to save files in AWS ECS Fargate instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, file-upload, filesystems, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am running java spring boot application on AWS ECS with fargate tasks. The applications has a REST Api exposed which facilitates users to upload images to S3.

Currently before publishing the file to S3, the application temporarily stores the image in local. The application works fine in my machine, but once deployed the application throws below error.

```
 "exception" : "java.io.IOException: File too large
```

The file size is very less (in KBs) and as far as i know, fargate comes with some default ephemeral storage which it can access, so i believe storage space is not the issue.

I am not able to figure out what might be causing this.

Appreciate any help towards solution!

Thanks

```
"exception" : "java.io.IOException: File too large
\n\tat java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)\n\tat 
java.base/java.io.FileOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.ThresholdingOutputStream.write(ThresholdingOutputStream.java:127)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.util.Streams.copy(Streams.java:104)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase.parseRequest(FileUploadBase.java:28
8)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.parseParts(Request.java:2932)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getParts(Request.java:2834)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getParts(RequestFacade.java:1098)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.parseRequest(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:95)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.<init>(StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest.java:88)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.resolveMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:122)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.checkMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1205)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1039)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)\n\tat
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\n\tat
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat 
com.inviz.bff.filter.SwaggerCorsFilter.doFilter(SwaggerCorsFilter.java:25)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat 
org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\n\tat
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\n\tat 
org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:540)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:895)\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1732)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\n\tat 
org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\n\tat 
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)\n"
2022-10-31T19:40:34.377+05:30
```

Comment: what is the filename ? if it is too large, same error message can be thrown.

Comment: The file name's relatively shorter. ex:- image-06_10_2022_11_10_25_067.jpg. Is this above the number of characters threshold? @muhammedozbilici

Comment: I am not sure but maybe related to that, can you try with simple name like abc.jpg ?